# Spring JMX cascading/federating

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans

I have a webapp running under Spring 3.2 and exposing a MBeanServer.
Nevertheless this webapp can be run through different VM and so have multiple instance of JVM on different VM.

I want to modify MBeans on each MBeanServer instance, and I know there is a concept of *cascading/federating* JMX, but I didn't find anything to implement it using Spring.

So there is a way to federate spring MBeanServer easily? The main goal is to modify MBeans on each "frontend".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDMK (now available as [OpenJDMK](https://opendmk.java.net/)) implements MBean Cascading. Basically, this means that a series of individual MBeanServers (in different JVMs, but not exclusively) are "resurfaced" inside of one central MBeanServer. For example, you might have a GarbageCollector MXBean called **java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep** in 5 seperate JVMs (A..E). The central console would have its own instance and then you would also see 5 additional instances registered in the same MBeanServer named something like:

```
 - //JVM-A/java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep
 - ....
 - //JVM-E/java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep
```

Here's an example screenshot of some cascades in my JConsole:

[image]

The documentation is available [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jdmk/jdmk_docs.html).
I also created a Maven friendly OpenJDMK build [here](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK), if that sort of thing is useful to you. (There's various different forked builds available on Sonatype Nexus too.)

** ===== UPDATE ===== **

Yeah, sorry about that. Looks like the OpenJDMK web site has been neglected of recent.

Here's a link to the [User Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7607/), and a shortcut to the [Cascading chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7607/components-35/index.html).
Here's a link to the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/), and a shortcut to the [Cascading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/6mdjrf87n/index.html).

The tutorial has a decent selection of code samples.

Comment: Hum documentation link does not work correctly on my side? :'(. So there is not Spring built-in support, I have to look for JDMK. If you have any sample I will be glad, because I'm a bit new with JMX/Java :)